# Is there any way to fetch the recycle bin items of share point office365 using graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there any way to fetch the share point O365 site's recycle bin items using graph API?
I am looking for option using IGraphServiceClient c# interface.

Comment: Did you check Microsoft Docs?

Comment: Yes I did  and was not able find any documentation support for the same.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

As you said there is no such Graph API call that can get data from the recycle bin. There is also a feature request already raised by some users in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39962176-allow-read-write-access-to-deleted-data-in-onedriv). Please upvote this feature so that the product team can implement it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This should be supported now for [beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/recyclebin-list-items?view=graph-rest-beta)